# Amplitude/Frequency chart in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to create amplitude/frequency chart in simulink for bandwidth measurement of a signal in Simulink. I have no idea how to do it and which blocks I should use. 
[my system in simulink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QonR.png)

Comment: If you have the `DSP Blockset` then you can use the [Spectrum Analyser](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/spectrumanalyzer.html) block.  If not, then you can write your own function to call `fft` to create the spectrum.

Comment: I have Spectrum Analyzer but I can't find Amplitude/Frequency chart

Comment: in spectrum analyzer I get dbm/freq plot but I need amp/freq for bandwidth measurement I have no idea how to do it.